# Saving form data in html to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form in HTML

```
<form class="form__filling contacts" action="applications.php" method="post">
            <div class="contacts__container flex">
              <label class="contacts__label" for="name" >
                <textarea class="contacts__input" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" id="name"></textarea>
              </label>

              <label class="contacts__label" for="phone">
                <textarea class="contacts__input form__input" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон"></textarea>
              </label>

              <label class="contacts__label form__label" for="email" >
                <textarea class="contacts__input form__input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Введите ваш email"></textarea>
              </label>
            </div>

            <button
              class="contacts__btn"
              type="submit"
            >
              ЗАПИСАТЬСЯ
            </button>
          </form>
```

There is an "applications" table in the "englishTochka" database in mySQL with columns: id, timestamp, name, phone, email.
I need to insert the data from the form into this table, for this I use PHP code

```
<?php
// Подключение к базе данных
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "admin";
$dbname = "englishTochka";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Проверка подключения
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Получение данных из формы
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// SQL-запрос для вставки данных в таблицу
$sql = "INSERT INTO applications (timestamp, name, phone, email) VALUES (NOW(), '$name', '$phone', '$email')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Запись успешно сохранена";
} else {
echo "Ошибка: " . $sql . "" . $conn->error;
}

// Закрытие соединения с базой данных
$conn->close();
?>
```

Every time I fill out the form data and click the "Submit" button, I have a message "HTTP ERROR 405". Please, help me solve this problem

i dont know what is wrong :([image: mySQL table]

Comment: Please note that the word 'timestamp' (which is one of the column names in your table) is a keyword in Mysql . See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) . On the other hand, please change your queries to parameterized prepared statements which are resilient against SQL injection

Comment: Could you please provide more details about error? As 405 means the source method is not matching with the method used at target.

Comment: @SnehalS, sorry, i have only information in my browser : "HTTP ERROR 405". I have a message in console "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ (index):6587" and "No resource with given URL found" after tapping this index. but i dont use any url in my form. if i misunderstood your question, tell me where to click and what information you need

Comment: @KenLee, I need to put the word "timestamp" in quotation marks like this: 
$sql = "INSERT INTO applications ('timestamp', name, phone, email) VALUES (NOW(), '$name', '$phone', '$email')"

i cant understand the second part of your answer, becouse i dont work with PHP and mySQL at all :(

Comment: `405 Method Not Allowed` is usually what you get, when the web server thinks you tried to make a POST request against a _static_ resource. Can you execute _any_ PHP functionality at all, in your current setup? The most likely reasons are that you are either not accessing this via HTTP to begin with (but only accessed the form HTML file in your browser _via_ the `file:///` protocol), or don't have PHP properly integrated into your web server setup.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if you just want to insert the current date/time into your table, set the default value in your table to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and leave it out of the query completely. I make a habit of not using reserved words for column names, saves a bit of typing and remembering which quotes to use.

Comment: @CBroe, how can i understand what is wrong? i dont have any experience with PHP

Comment: _"how can i understand what is wrong?"_ - well I just told you two possible reasons. Assuming it is not the access-via-file-system issue, and you _did_ load the form page in your browser using `http://`(or `https://`), it would indicate that your web server is not properly set up to send files with the `.php` suffix through the PHP parser.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: To make your code more robust (unless you're on PHP 8.1 or above where this is already enabled by default), add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident.